# MySQL Iterating over tables where table name is a parameter

Tags: mysql

I have a database "devicemanagement" containing sensor ID's, and sensor details (like location, type etc), the key field for this table is the sensorID itself.

TABLE devicemanagement:

```
ID LOCATION   TYPE
+--+---------|-------+ 
|A | ROOM 1  | DOOR  | 
|B | ROOM 2  | TOILET|
+--+---------+-------+
```

Per SensorID, I have a table (named with the sensorIdvalue) where the sensor measurement data is stored.

```
TABLE "A" (Sensor A ID)
 ID DATE                   Value
+--+---------------------|--------+ 
|1 | 2022-02-07 12:23:11 | OPENED | 
|2 | 2022-02-07 13:11:12 | CLOSED |
+--+---------------------+--------+
```

TABLE "B" (Sensor B ID)

```
ID  DATE                   Value
+--+---------------------|---------+ 
|1 | 2022-02-07 12:13:23 | FLUSHED | 
|2 | 2022-02-07 12:24:44 | FLUSHED |
+--+---------------------+---------+
```

What I would like to have is a query that gives me:

- Per sensor (A, B, ...)

  - Get the Sensor details (table devicemanagement)
  - Added with the last measurement value (highest id)

so:

```
ID   LOCATION   TYPE     DATE                 VALUE
+--+----------+--------|---------------------+--------+
|A | ROOM 1   | DOOR   | 2022-02-07 13:11:12 | CLOSED |
|B | ROOM 2   | TOILET | 2022-02-07 12:24:44 | FLUSHED|
+--+----------+--------|---------------------+--------+
```

But I have tried to use joins, loops, but all failed.
Does anybody have a suggestion how to approach this query?

Comment: Highest ID doesn't necessarily mean it's the most recent row, use the datetime for that. I wonder why you create a new table for each sensor. Why not put all sensors data in one table, with a column sensorId?

Comment: Hello Daniel,
As there will be a lot of data per sensor (1M records per sensor easily), making it heavy to query if you have want to have all the doors or airquality sensor data.